# Putting multiple forms on the same page

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms

I've got a php / ajax form that works 100% ... but I need a few of the same form on the **SAME** page. Of course each of the forms will go to a different recipient.

I tried duplicating the form and it seems very complicated! I've tried submitting the duplicated form (with lots of edits to the duplicated form to try get it working) but no success
I don't know if what I am doing is right.
How the form goes is, I have a button when clicked, it toggleslides the div which contains the form... fill in the form, hit submit and an ajax success message pops up saying thank you

HTML FORM:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="accommodation_listing_options_box">
<ul id="accommodation_listing_options">
  <li>Price Range: <a href="#" class="tooltip" style="cursor:help;" title="Mid-range 
Accommodation"><img src="../mid-range-yellow.png" width="28" height="19" 
align="absmiddle" style="padding-left:0px;" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">View 
Comments</a> <img src="../comments_bubble_small.png" width="18" height="16" 
align="absmiddle" style="padding-left:5px;" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="quick_enquiry_box">Make Quick Enquiry</div>
<div style="clear:both; width:710px;"></div>



<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div id="slide_panel">
<div id="contact">

        <div id="message"></div>

        <form method="post" action="contact.php" name="contactform"    
id="contactform">
<div id="my_contact_left">



        <label for="name" accesskey="U"><span class="required">*
</span>Name</label><br />
        <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30" />

        <br />
        <label for="email" accesskey="E"><span class="required">*
</span>Email</label><br />
        <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30" />

        <br />
        <label for="phone" accesskey="P"><span class="required">*
</span>Phone:</label><br />
        <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" size="30" />

        <br />
        <label for="dayin" accesskey="P">Day in:</label><br />

        <input name="dayin" class="datepicker" type="text" id="dayin" 
size="30" />

        <br />
        <label for="dayout" accesskey="P">Day out:</label><br />
        <input name="dayout" class="datepicker2" type="text" id="dayout" 
size="30" />


</div>
<div id="my_contact_right">

        <label for="comments" accesskey="C"><span class="required">*
</span>Your Comments</label><br />
        <textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="3" id="comments" 
style="width: 350px; height:100px;"></textarea>

        <p><span class="required">*</span>Type the validation code in 
below</p>

        <div style="width:100px; height:40px; float:left;"><label 
for="verify" accesskey="V">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="image.php" alt="Image 
verification" border="0"/></label></div>
        <div style="width:310px; height:40px; float:right;"><input 
name="verify" type="text" id="verify" size="6" value="" style="width: 50px;" />
        <input type="submit" style="margin-left:112px;" class="submit" 
id="submit" value="Send it!" /></div>
        <div style="clear:both; width:410px;"></div>

</div>
<div style="clear:both; width:710px;"></div>

        </form>
</div>
<div id="quick_form_wrapper_close"><a href="#"><img src="../close-panel-button.gif" 
/></a></div>
</div>



</div>
</body>
```

If I make a duplicated form, what I need to change in the HTML code is the following:

```
action="contact.php" name="contactform"    
id="contactform"
```

to:

```
action="contact2.php" name="contactform2"    
id="contactform2"
```

Is this correct? Anything else I need to change in the HTML?

Moving onto the Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

$('#contactform').submit(function(){

    var action = $(this).attr('action');

    $('#submit').attr('disabled','disabled').after('<img src="assets/ajax-
loader.gif" class="loader" />');

    $("#message").slideUp(750,function() {
    $('#message').hide();

    $.post(action, {
        name: $('#name').val(),
        email: $('#email').val(),
        phone: $('#phone').val(),
        dayin: $('#dayin').val(),
        dayout: $('#dayout').val(),
        comments: $('#comments').val(),
        verify: $('#verify').val()
    },
        function(data){
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
            $('#message').slideDown('slow');
            $('#contactform img.loader').fadeOut('fast',function()
{$(this).remove()});
            $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
            if(data.match('success') != null);
            $("#message").show().delay(5000).fadeOut();

        }
    );

    });
```

Do I need to make the field ID's different duplicating a form on the same page?
EG:

```
$.post(action, {
        name2: $('#name2').val(),
        email2: $('#email2').val(),
        phone2: $('#phone2').val(),
        dayin2: $('#dayin2').val(),
        dayout2: $('#dayout2').val(),
        comments2: $('#comments2').val(),
        verify2: $('#verify2').val()
    },
```

Do I need to do any changes to the PHP process form? 
Here is the main part of the php process form:

```
$name    = $_POST['name'];
$email  = $_POST['email'];
$phone  = $_POST['phone'];
$dayin  = $_POST['dayin'];
$dayout = $_POST['dayout'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];

if (isset($_POST['verify'])) :
    $posted_verify   = $_POST['verify'];
    $posted_verify   = md5($posted_verify);
else :
    $posted_verify = '';
endif;

// Important Variables
$session_verify = $_SESSION['verify'];

if (empty($session_verify)) $session_verify = $_COOKIE['verify'];

$error = '';

    if(trim($name) == '') {
        $error .= '<li>Your name is required.</li>';
    }

    if(trim($email) == '') {
        $error .= '<li>Your e-mail address is required.</li>';
    } elseif(!isEmail($email)) {
        $error .= '<li>You have entered an invalid e-mail address.</li>';
    }

    if(trim($phone) == '') {
        $error .= '<li>Your phone number is required.</li>';
    } elseif(!is_numeric($phone)) {
        $error .= '<li>Your phone number can only contain digits.</li>';
    }

    if(trim($comments) == '') {
        $error .= '<li>You must enter a message to send.</li>';
    }

    if($session_verify != $posted_verify) {
        $error .= '<li>The verification code you entered is incorrect.
</li>';
    }

    if($error != '') {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please correct the 
 errors below and try again.';
        echo '<ul class="error_messages">' . $error . '</ul>';
        echo '</div>';

    } else {

    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) { $comments = stripslashes($comments); }

     // Advanced Configuration Option.
     // i.e. The standard subject will appear as, "You've been contacted by 
John Doe."

     $e_subject = 'You\'ve been contacted by ' . $name . '.';

     // Advanced Configuration Option.
     // You can change this if you feel that you need to.
     // Developers, you may wish to add more fields to the form, in which case 
you must be sure to add them here.

     $msg  = "You have been contacted by $name with regards to Accommodation. 
They passed verification and their message is as follows." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
     $msg .= "$comments" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
     $msg .= "You can contact $name via email, $email or via phone $phone." . 
PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
     $msg .= "We want to stay from the $dayin to the $dayout" . PHP_EOL . 
PHP_EOL;
     $msg .= 
"---------------------------------------------------------------------------
-" . PHP_EOL;


    if($twitter_active == 1) {

        $twitter_msg = $name . " - " . $comments . ". You can contact " . 
$name . " via email, " . $email ." or via phone " . $phone . ".";
        twittermessage($twitter_user, $twitter_msg, $consumer_key, 
$consumer_secret, $token, $secret);

    }

    $msg = wordwrap( $msg, 70 );

    $headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

    if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

     echo "<fieldset>";
     echo "<div id='success_page'>";
     echo "<strong>Email Sent Successfully.</strong>";
     echo "</div>";
     echo "</fieldset>";

     } else {

     echo 'ERROR!'; // Dont Edit.

     }

}
```

Thanks in advance! Really appreciate your help because I have tried for hours and I haven't got it right yet!

**EDIT:**
MY CURRENT JAVASCRIPT CODING:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

$('.contactform').submit(function(){

    var action = $(this).attr('action');

    $('.submit').attr('disabled','disabled').after('<img src="assets/ajax-
loader.gif" class="loader" />');

    $("#message").slideUp(750,function() {
    $('#message').hide();

    $.post(action, {
        name: $('.name').val(),
        email: $('.email').val(),
        phone: $('.phone').val(),
        dayin: $('.dayin').val(),
        dayout: $('.dayout').val(),
        comments: $('.comments').val(),
        verify: $('.verify').val()
    },
        function(data){
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
            $('#message').slideDown('slow');
            $('.contactform img.loader').fadeOut('fast',function()
{$(this).remove()});
            $('.submit').removeAttr('disabled');
            if(data.match('success') != null);
            $("#message").show().delay(5000).fadeOut();

        }
    );

    });

    return false;

});

});

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

$('.contactform2').submit(function(){

    var action = $(this).attr('action');

    $('.submit').attr('disabled','disabled').after('<img src="assets/ajax-
loader.gif" class="loader" />');

    $("#message2").slideUp(750,function() {
    $('#message2').hide();

    $.post(action, {
        name: $('.name').val(),
        email: $('.email').val(),
        phone: $('.phone').val(),
        dayin: $('.dayin').val(),
        dayout: $('.dayout').val(),
        comments: $('.comments').val(),
        verify: $('.verify').val()
    },
        function(data){
            document.getElementById('message2').innerHTML = data;
            $('#message2').slideDown('slow');
            $('.contactform2 img.loader').fadeOut('fast',function()
{$(this).remove()});
            $('.submit').removeAttr('disabled');
            if(data.match('success') != null);
            $("#message2").show().delay(5000).fadeOut();

        }
    );

    });

    return false;

});

});
```

MY CURRENT JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

$('.contactform').submit(function(){

    var action = $(this).attr('action');

    $(this).children('.submit').attr('disabled','disabled').after('<img 
src="assets/ajax-loader.gif" class="loader" />');

    $(this).children("#message").slideUp(750,function() {
    $(this).children('#message').hide();

    $.post(action, {
        name: $(this).children('.name').val(),
        email: $(this).children('.email').val(),
        phone: $(this).children('.phone').val(),
        dayin: $(this).children('.dayin').val(),
        dayout: $(this).children('.dayout').val(),
        comments: $(this).children('.comments').val(),
        verify: $(this).children('.verify').val()

    },
        function(data){
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
            $(this).children('#message').slideDown('slow');
            $(this).children('.contactform 
img.loader').fadeOut('fast',function(){$(this).remove()});
            $(this).children('.submit').removeAttr('disabled');
            if(data.match('success') != null);
            $(this).children("#message").show().delay(5000).fadeOut();

        }
    );

    });

    return false;

});

});
```

Comment: When I was working on a project with multiple forms on a single page, I used a hidden field:
`<input type="hidden" name="formname" value="form name" />` and had all the forms submit their fields to the very same file called for example `formProcessor.php`. Maybe this solution is suitable in your case, too?

Comment: Do you want to submit the same form to multiple locations, or do you want the user to fill out many forms and these are submitted to different locations? I guess i don't understand why you would have the exact same form multiple times ?

Comment: @Pateman 
Thanks. I will give this a try though I think the complication here is the javascript file (posted in my question above)? Because the javascript verifies the form if its been sent successfully or not. I dont know if I need to change anything there?

Remember there is AJAX involved here and the success message displays in a div in the form

Comment: @DaleHughes, not really. Just have the `formProcessor.php` echo some message, preferably with `die()`, so that the AJAX request can display it using `$('#message').html(data);`, which you already have in there, but written in pure Javascript. :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using IDs for the jquery selectors, use classes. You can give all of the forms the same class name and the fields that are the same get the same classes as well.

Then, use those in your jquery:

```
$('.contactform').submit(function(){
    $.post(action, {
        name: $(this).children('.name').val(),
```

It should work for however many instances of the form you have because all of the input fields are referenced by $(this), which is the submitted form, regardless of id or name.

EDIT:

This should work for you. For any number of forms, this is all you would need.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    $('.contactform').submit(function(){

        var action = $(this).attr('action');

        $('.submit', this).attr('disabled','disabled').after('<img src="assets/ajax-loader.gif" class="loader" />');

        $('.message', this).slideUp(750,function() {
        $('.message', this).hide();

        $.post(action, {
            name: $('.name', this).val(),
            email: $('.email', this).val(),
            phone: $('.phone', this).val(),
            dayin: $('.dayin', this).val(),
            dayout: $('.dayout', this).val(),
            comments: $('.comments', this).val(),
            verify: $('.verify', this).val()
        },
        function(data){
                $('.message', this).html(data);
                $('.message', this).slideDown('slow');
                $('img.loader', this).fadeOut('fast',function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
                $('.submit', this).removeAttr('disabled');
            if(data.match('success') != null);
                $('.message', this).show().delay(5000).fadeOut();
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: You only really need 1 section of jQuery, there is no need to number a new class for each form. Basically when using the $('.contactform') selector the code will fire when the form is submitted and that form will become $(this). I hope that makes sense. So when you use the loader and the message reference it with $(this).children('.message');.   Same thing for the form values.I will try and edit and then repost to my answer.

Comment: Yes, exactly, the dom object that is selected become $(this), basically. Then you can use 'this' in your selector to narrow down the dom when making further selections. Take a look at the edited code and that should get you pretty close. $('.submit', this), as an example, basically means look for the object with a submit class within the form that was submitted.

Comment: The code in my edit above should work, I would imagine it will work without any edits and will support any number of forms. You do not need to duplicate it at all.

Comment: Ok, I've put that code in, tested it to see if it works and when I click on the submit button the loading gif shows up in that particular form (which is perfect), though there are no error / success messages showing. Must be something to do with the coding below "function(data)" ??

Comment: Did you change your HTML to make "message" a class rather than an id?

Comment: Just for clarification. Classes are meant to be used for
Multiple Dom objects on a page, where id's are to be used if the Dom object is unique. If jQuery runs into an ID it will only affect the first one in the dom. Which explains why only one loader would spin.

Comment: Ah. You message div is outside the form so it can't be seen within the form $(this). Move the message div just after the opening form tag.

Comment: I actually did that a little earlier while experimenting and nothing happened. I did it now and unfortunately still nothing, though I do see the form moving a bit almost like it wants to show a success / error message! I'm sure we almost there, I can't see anything wrong at the moment ...

Comment: Hi John, just to let you know that my issue on this question has been resolved! Thanks so much for your help! Please click here to see the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357127/success-error-messages-on-form-submit-not-showing-resolved