# Success / Error Messages on form Submit not showing 

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, forms

I have a php / ajax / javascript form that I am trying to get to work. With a great deal of help from John Fable, I just need to get the success and error messages to show.
See our thread here:
[Putting multiple forms on the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347692/putting-multiple-forms-on-the-same-page)

My form is at:
http://www.testing123.co.za/try/test-toggle.htm

My object was to get have multiple forms on 1 page, but at the moment when you click submit on either form, the success or error message doesn't show and instead a loading gif spins near the submit button.

Javascript for the form goes like:

```
 // JavaScript Document

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('.contactform').submit(function() {
        var action = $(this).attr('action');
        $('.submit', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled').after('<img src="assets/ajax-
loader.gif" class="loader" />');
        $('.message', this).slideUp(750, function() {
            $('.message', this).hide();
            $.post(action, {
                name: $('.name', this).val(),
                email: $('.email', this).val(),
                phone: $('.phone', this).val(),
                dayin: $('.dayin', this).val(),
                dayout: $('.dayout', this).val(),
                comments: $('.comments', this).val(),
                verify: $('.verify', this).val()
            },
            function(data) {
                $('.message', this).html(data);
                $('.message', this).slideDown('slow');
                $('img.loader', this).fadeOut('fast', function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
                $('.submit', this).removeAttr('disabled');
                if (data.match('success') != null);
                $('.message', this).show().delay(5000).fadeOut();
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

HTML FORM:

```
<body>

<div id="container">

<div id="accommodation_listing_options_box">

 <ul id="accommodation_listing_options">

  <li>Price Range: <a href="#" class="tooltip" style="cursor:help;" title="Mid-range 
 Accommodation"><img src="../mid-range-yellow.png" width="28" height="19" 
 align="absmiddle" style="padding-left:0px;" /></a></li>

  <li><a href="#">View Comments</a> <img src="../comments_bubble_small.png" width="18" 
 height="16" align="absmiddle" style="padding-left:5px;" /></li>

</ul>

</div>

<div id="quick_enquiry_box">Make Quick Enquiry</div>

<div style="clear:both; width:710px;"></div>



<div style="clear:both;"></div>

<div id="slide_panel">

<div id="contact">

        <form method="post" action="contact.php" name="contactform" id="contactform" 
class="contactform"><div class="message"></div>

<div id="my_contact_left">



        <label for="name" accesskey="U"><span class="required">*</span>Name</label><br 
 />

        <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30" class="name" />

        <br />

        <label for="email" accesskey="E"><span class="required">*
  </span>Email</label><br />

        <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30" class="email" />

        <br />

        <label for="phone" accesskey="P"><span class="required">*</span>Phone:
 </label><br />

        <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" size="30" class="phone" />

        <br />

        <label for="dayin" accesskey="P">Day in:</label><br />

        <input name="dayin" type="text" id="dayin" size="30" class="dayin" />

        <br />

        <label for="dayout" accesskey="P">Day out:</label><br />

        <input name="dayout" type="text" id="dayout" size="30" class="dayout" />

 </div>

<div id="my_contact_right">

        <label for="comments" accesskey="C"><span class="required">*</span>Your 
Comments</label><br />

        <textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="3" id="comments" class="comments" 
style="width: 350px; height:100px;"></textarea>

        <p><span class="required">*</span>Type the validation code in below</p>

        <div style="width:100px; height:40px; float:left;"><label for="verify" 
accesskey="V">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="image.php" alt="Image verification" 
border="0"/></label></div>

        <div style="width:310px; height:40px; float:right;"><input name="verify" 
type="text" id="verify" class="verify" size="6" value="" style="width: 50px;" />

        <input type="submit" style="margin-left:112px;" class="submit" id="submit" 
value="Send it!" /></div>

        <div style="clear:both; width:410px;"></div>

</div>

<div style="clear:both; width:710px;"></div>

        </form>

</div>

<div id="quick_form_wrapper_close"><a href="#"><img src="../close-panel-button.gif" 
/></a>
</div>

</div>



<div id="accommodation_listing_options_box">

<ul id="accommodation_listing_options">

  <li>Price Range: <a href="#" class="tooltip" style="cursor:help;" title="Mid-range 
Accommodation"><img src="../mid-range-yellow.png" width="28" height="19" 
align="absmiddle" style="padding-left:0px;" /></a></li>

  <li><a href="#">View Comments</a> <img src="../comments_bubble_small.png" width="18" 
height="16" align="absmiddle" style="padding-left:5px;" /></li>

</ul>

</div>

<div id="quick_enquiry_box2">Make Quick Enquiry</div>

<div style="clear:both; width:710px;"></div>



<div style="clear:both;"></div>

<div id="slide_panel2">

<div id="contact">



        <form method="post" action="contact2.php" name="contactform" id="contactform" 
class="contactform"><div class="message"></div>

<div id="my_contact_left">



        <label for="name" accesskey="U"><span class="required">*</span>Name</label><br 
/>

        <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30" class="name" />

        <br />

        <label for="email" accesskey="E"><span class="required">*
</span>Email</label><br />

        <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30" class="email" />

        <br />

        <label for="phone" accesskey="P"><span class="required">*</span>Phone:
</label><br />

        <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" size="30" class="phone" />

        <br />

        <label for="dayin" accesskey="P">Day in:</label><br />

        <input name="dayin" type="text" id="dayin" size="30" class="dayin" />

        <br />

        <label for="dayout" accesskey="P">Day out:</label><br />

        <input name="dayout" type="text" id="dayout" size="30" class="dayout" />

</div>

<div id="my_contact_right">

        <label for="comments" accesskey="C"><span class="required">*</span>Your 
Comments</label><br />

        <textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="3" id="comments" class="comments" 
style="width: 350px; height:100px;"></textarea>

        <p><span class="required">*</span>Type the validation code in below</p>

        <div style="width:100px; height:40px; float:left;"><label for="verify" 
accesskey="V">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="image.php" alt="Image verification" 
border="0"/></label></div>

        <div style="width:310px; height:40px; float:right;"><input name="verify" 
type="text" id="verify" class="verify" size="6" value="" style="width: 50px;" />

        <input type="submit" style="margin-left:112px;" class="submit" id="submit" 
value="Send it!" /></div>

        <div style="clear:both; width:410px;"></div>

</div>

<div style="clear:both; width:710px;"></div>

        </form>

</div>

<div id="quick_form_wrapper_close2"><a href="#"><img src="../close-panel-button.gif" 
/></a>    </div>

</div>

</div>

</body>
```

The success / error message should appear in the div:

`<div class="message"></div>` which you can see is in the html form above.

Any ideas why the success / error messages arn't showing upon submit?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are many issues with your markup. The fact that I'm too lazy to read it proves it. It's messy, you have access lines everywhere, you use inline styling, and you use `<br>` for line break. All of those must be fixed. Nice and tidy code gives you much less headache in the future. I might also solve your problem.

Comment: i'd just like to agree with @Truth - your js is formatted fine, but please for the love of all that is good and holy in the world format (and indent!!!) your html, all the time, from now on. It makes these little errors 1000000% easier to spot - and also random internet people will be more inclined to check it for you in future.

EDIT: actually one criticism for your JS - please use curly braces on if statements. It's not required if it's a one liner but again, makes these things easier to spot.

Comment: Agreed, also avoid placing useless attributes where they are not needed (especially ids, and don't repeat them), and use CSS for styling anywhere it's possible.

Comment: @jammypeach of course his JS is formatted fine, I formatted it for him :). Also, take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/AFnDY/1/ doesn't it look much better? (coding-wise)

Comment: @Truth LMFAO that tickled me :D

Comment: Hi, Thank guys for your responses! What did you do to the JS? I don't see any difference or am I just code blind? I do understand that my html isn't so hot! I will neaten it up and remove inline styling and put them in a css. The code at JS fiddle does look a lot better though I am styling the form to look different to your preview on JS fiddle. The forms success / error messaging was working on tests I did before John Fable came and helped me, so I don't think the HTML could have given me my current issue?

Comment: Ok I removed the semicolon and replaced my javascript with the edit code that TRUTH did. When I click submit, the success / error message shows but doesn't show in the div class MESSAGE ... it takes me to http://www.testing123.co.za/try/contact.php which shows the messages there. So basically the messages arn't showing up AJAX style in the message div ...

Comment: Ok, I noticed a mistake I did and corrected it. When I click submit, we are back to square 1. Hmmmmmmmmm...

Comment: Your parameters are not getting passed in the post request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (probably still not 100% correct):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('.contactform').submit(function() {
        var action = $(this).attr('action');
        var form = this;
        $('.submit', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled').after(
              '<img src="assets/ajax-loader.gif" class="loader" />');
        $('.message', this).slideUp(750, function() {
            $(this).hide();
            $.post(action, {
                name: $('.name', form).val(),
                email: $('.email', form).val(),
                phone: $('.phone', form).val(),
                dayin: $('.dayin', form).val(),
                dayout: $('.dayout', form).val(),
                comments: $('.comments', form).val(),
                verify: $('.verify', form).val()
            },
            function(data) {
                $('.message', form).html(data);
                $('.message', form).slideDown('slow');
                $('img.loader', form).fadeOut('fast', function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
                $('.submit', form).removeAttr('disabled');
                if (data.match('success') != null)
                $('.message', form).show().delay(5000).fadeOut();
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: well spotted, i missed that :)

Comment: Are you saying I need to put an extra semicolon or remove it?

Comment: remove it: that semicolon means the "then" part of the if is empty.

Comment: Ok, I used TRUTH's JS and removed the semicolon and its not showing the error / success messages in the "message" div like it should but instead takes me to contact.php where it shows the messages there.

Comment: try to change `$('.contactform').submit(function() {
        var action = $(this).attr('action');` to `$('.contactform').submit(function(e) { e.preventDefault();
        var action = $(this).attr('action');`

Comment: Fix this line in you JS: `$('.submit', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled').after('<img src="assets/ajax-
loader.gif" class="loader" />');`, it should be on a single line.

Comment: @Semyazas he's already using `return false` (and besides, it worked before) so that's not the issue.

Comment: Probably found it: inside the slideUp handler, this refers to the element being animated (.message), so $('.email', this) is meaningless.

Comment: Thanks Viruzzo, thats what I spotted and corrected. So with the JS looking 100%, howcome it still doesn't display the success / error messages? Does the contact.php have a role in this issue?

Comment: @Viruzzo - So you are saying that the slideup is no use when we have: $('.message', this).hide(); ??

Comment: @DaleHughes not at all, just that inside the slideUp this is the div.comment, so $('.email', this) meaning "class email inside div class comment" obviously returns nothing.

Comment: @DaleHughes not remove, but change the context. Check my edited answer (though I just spotted a leftover this).

Comment: Woopah!! Your edit worked!!!!!!!!! :) I grant you a 6 pack of cyber beers, hahaha!
I just copied and pasted your edit. What did you change, just LIKE to FORM?